# Hyperlink occurs empty space also for Centered text

Tags: hyperref, luatex

Using `LuaLaTeX`, I am getting hyperlink anchors in unwanted places, shown in the MWE (`PDFLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX` produces prompt output). I only want the actual text to function as an anchor, not the surrounding whitespace.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\href{www.google.com}{Text for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase only}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: MWE-Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly experimental and might change, but you can try a package I'm working on for this:

Download [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zauguin/lua-links/trunk/lua-links.dtx) and save it as `lua-links.sty` next to your document. Then load the `lua-links` package with the `discard` option:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[discard]{lua-links}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\href{www.google.com}{Text for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase only}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Appreciated for your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid that you must break the line manually and use a \href on every one. Personally I would avoid such a large link area completely, it is imho quite a nuisance if too large parts of a document are active.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\href{www.google.com}{Text for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase only}

\bigskip

\href{www.google.com}{Text for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for Testingphase}\\
\href{www.google.com}{onlyText for Testingphase
onlyText for Testingphase onlyText for}\\
\href{www.google.com}{Testingphase only}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, we required hyperlink for larger text part as per the MWE provided. Though this is quite a nuisance request, is it possible to get a solution like the way we are getting with PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX.

Comment: @KumareshPS you could try https://github.com/zauguin/lua-links